# W: Invalid 'Date' entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_var_cuda-repo-8-0-local_Release

Tags: 16.04, command-line, apt, package-management, updates

When I run

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

I get

```
sudo apt-get update                                                
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local  Release [574 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local  Release [574 B]
Get:3 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local  Release.gpg [819 B]                                                                                   
Get:3 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local  Release.gpg [819 B]                                                          
Hit:4 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease                                                                                                              
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                  
Ign:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                            
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                                                                                                       
Hit:8 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                              
Hit:9 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                                                                      
Hit:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                                             
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/clipgrab-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                  
Hit:12 http://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable InRelease                                                      
Hit:13 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                                                     
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                       
Hit:15 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                   
Hit:16 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                        
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                               
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease                           
Ign:19 http://archive.canonical.com precise InRelease                                              
Hit:21 http://archive.canonical.com precise Release 
Hit:22 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
Hit:24 https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done 
W: Invalid 'Date' entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_var_cuda-repo-8-0-local_Release
W: http://archive.canonical.com/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

Can / should I do anything because of the following warning?

```
W: Invalid 'Date' entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_var_cuda-repo-8-0-local_Release
```

Comment: Can you check your current system time using the `date` command and verify it is correct? Also can you please add the output of `date --iso-8601='seconds' ; grep -r "Date:" /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_var_cuda-repo-8-0-local_Release ; ls --full-time /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_var_cuda-repo-8-0-local_Release`

Answer (score 1):

First, you seem to be running 16.04 (Xenial), but still have some old 12.04 (Precise) repositories configured. You should really remove them.

For the other warning, probably the file got corrupted somehow, either on your machine or on the server from which it got downloaded. You can safely delete it:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_var_cuda-repo-8-0-local_Release
```

Or even delete the whole lists folder:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
```

After that, you have to make Ubuntu download/update all the lists again:

```
sudo apt update
```

This time the warning should be gone. If not, wait a day or a few more and repeat, in case the file is probably broken on the server.

Comment: `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_var_cuda-repo-8-0-local_Release` does not change anything

Comment: `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists` doesn't change anything